# How to fix outliers in Ramachandran plot using Coot

Tags: crystallography, proteins, pdb

I have the following Ramachandran plot generated by **[Coot](https://www2.mrc-lmb.cam.ac.uk/personal/pemsley/coot/)**:

[image]

Notice that it has high outliers content (red dots). I want to manually drag those
red dots into some part of the region. Eventually, I expect it to be reflected
in the coordinates so that I can save it as a new PDB file.

How can I achieve this?

G.V.

Comment: Asked also on other SE sites:
https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/108763/how-to-fix-outliers-in-ramachandran-plot-using-coot  
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/166434/how-to-fix-outliers-in-ramachandran-plot-using-coot and on the Coot mailing list:
https://www.jiscmail.ac.uk/cgi-bin/wa-jisc.exe?A2=COOT;8b1a81dd.2207

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but just came today to check how things are going? Did you figure out the answer? Are you still working on this? Let us know! I noticed that the question was deleted from Chem.SE, and got no response form Biology.SE nor the jiscmail.ac.uk mailing list. It has attracted 178 views though (I'm not sure if this was from marcin pointing the other sites to the question here, or if it was from Google searches), but surprisingly the Biology.SE version has only 62 views, so a maximum of 62 would have come from there and probably a lot less).